# how do I get the data from my List<CustomObject>

Tags: c#, list

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error  CS0030  Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'Calendar.CalendarModel'

```
private void findManagerForSelectedDate(String dateSelected)
{
    List<String> managerNames = new List<String>();
    foreach(var item in managers)
    {
        CalendarModel c = item;
        Console.WriteLine(c.date);
    }
}
```

Basically I want to match the date passed in as a parameter with a date in the "managers" List

the Managers variable is declared as

```
private List<List<CalendarModel>> managers = new List<List<CalendarModel>>();
```

My CalendarModel is defined like

```
namespace Calendar
{
    class CalendarModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("date")]
        public string date { get; set; }
```

Obviously my code to match the date is not yet implemented. I am having trouble getting the date from my List

Comment: `managers` is defined as a list of a list, are you sure this is intentional? How about `private List<CalendarModel> managers = new List<CalendarModel>();`.

Comment: Yea it's intentional. I am storing a List of a List. I've never really worked with double Lists before and maybe I am overthinking the problem. :(

Comment: In that case in your foreach loop, your `item` will be of type List<CalendarModel>, you will need another foreach on `item` to access the date property of each CalendarModel contained in item.

Comment: in `findManagerForSelectedDate' your manager is `CalendarModel` while in the declaration the type of managers is `List<List<CalendarModel>>()`. It's not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'managers' field is a list of lists of CalendarModel:

```
List<List<CalendarModel>>
```

But you cast 'List of CalendarModel`s' to CalendarModel in foreach loop.

```
    foreach(var item in managers)
    {
        CalendarModel c = item; // 'item' is List<CalendarModel>, but you cast it to CalendarModel.
        Console.WriteLine(c.date);
    }
```

You can change type of your 'managers' field to:

```
List<CalendarModel> managers = new List<CalendarModel>();
```

Or use 2 foreach loops:

```
        foreach(var item in managers)
        {
            foreach(var subitem in item)
            {
                CalendarModel c = subitem;
                Console.WriteLine(c.date);
            }
        }
```

Comment: if I use two for loops, will that be efficient? Because the first list will ALWAYS contain 23 items. But the second list may contain hundreds of items

Comment: Yes, this code is quite effective. For several thousands of iterations is enough.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in your foreach loop `item` is of type `List<CalendarModel>`, you could use another foreach loop to access the `date` property on each `CalendarModel`in that list.

```
foreach(var items in managers)
foreach(var item in items )
{
    CalendarModel c = item;
    Console.WriteLine(c.date);
}
```